# using maven to fetch code from git + perform build + package into a jar + finally zip the complete folder containing jar and resources

Tags: java, git, maven

Hi from past 3 days i have been looking for a solution for my requirement but not getting help it will be great if someone can give me an idea how to go about it

my requirement:

i have source code in git in below structure:

```
Toolcode
 - sources
   - src
     - main/java/.*java
     - main/resources

 -lib
   - all dependencies like log4j etc
```

i want to fetch this code on my local machine and then refer the src and lib folder and build the code and package it as jar and place in a new folder called LIB and finally zip this folder LIB .

Can this be done using one single pom.xml file?

Comment: What it the reason not to use the [maven standard directory structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)? As you are using maven I would propose to use it. An explanation why it's worth to do so http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html

Comment: A lib directory shows that you didn't understand the concept of Maven, cause all dependencies will automatically downloaded from Maven Central or an appropriate repository (in corporate environment usually an internal repository manager). And of course change to [default folder layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Answer (score 1):

maven 3 build type does this

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>projectgroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

use this in pom.xml all this is done while creating project itself

Answer (score 0):

Below `pom.xml` would build as you which. With `mvn package` you can generate a Jar file `./lib/Toolcode-1.0-SNAPSHOT-with-dependencies.jar` which contains all dependencies.

As long there is not a compelling reason to do so I would propose to use the Maven standard directory structure.

**structure of directory `Toolcode` before build**

```
./pom.xml
./sources/src/main/java/sub/optimal/toolcode/Main.java
```

**`class` and `jar` files created by `mvn package`**

```
./lib/classes/sub/optimal/toolcode/Main.class
./lib/maven-archiver/pom.properties
./lib/Toolcode-1.0-SNAPSHOT-with-dependencies.jar
./lib/Toolcode-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

pom.xml (for non default directory structure)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sub.optimal</groupId>
    <artifactId>Toolcode</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/lib</directory>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/sources/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/sources/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compileSourceRoots>
                        <compileSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/sources/src/main/java/</compileSourceRoot>
                    </compileSourceRoots>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <quiet>true</quiet>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-with-dependencies</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: If you suggest to use the defaults why are you defining `directory`, `sourceDirectory`, `testSourcesDirectory` etc. Remove it, cause the defaults are already defined by Maven.

Comment: As per my understanding the requestor does not want to use the default directory structure. With the pom in my answer he could build with his mentioned structure. As not using the default structure has some drawbacks, I suggest the requestor to use the default structure. I updated my answer to make this different more clear.